# QSortFilterProxyModel with QStandardItemModel after appendRow are not working

Tags: qt, qt4, qstandarditemmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

Here what I have got:

- a `QTreeView` widget (*);
- Source model `MainModel` inherits from `QStandardItemModel`. No virtual `data() const` method reimplemented;
- Proxy `MainFilterProxyModel` inherits from `QSortFilterProxyModel`;

The tree:

```
[PERIOD 1]
   [CHILD 1]
   [CHILD 2]
      [SUBCHILD 2.1]
      ...
   [CHILD N]
[PERIOD 2]
...
[PERIOD N]
```

So the main problem comes when I'm trying to add a **CHILD-row** like (**) code do. Filter proxy model, after document was added to source model, does not know about new row and didn't show it on the tree.

I'm sure that proxy didn't get signal from `QStandardItemModel` when `appendRow` method do his job, so proxy can't filter new row, and didn't make it visible.

Any help?

Thanks.

PS: If I turn off proxy, everything appended just fine. But the problem is not in proxy. Proxy just doesn't get the signal about new row appended to the main source model...

---

(*) *Here is `QTreeView`*:

```
MainView::MainView( QWidget* parent /* = 0 */ ) : QTreeView( parent )
{
     if( !model_ )
     {
          model_ = new MainModel( this );
     }

     if( !proxy_ )
     {
          proxy_ = new MainFilterProxyModel( this );
          proxy_->setDynamicSortFilter( true );
          proxy_->setSourceModel( model_ );

          setModel( proxy_ );
     }
}
```

---

(**) *Here is my append function*:

```
void MainModel::addRow( const DocumentPtr& document, QStandardItem* parentItem )
{
     assert( document );

     QList< QStandardItem* > items;
     items << ( new QStandardItem );
     items << ( new QStandardItem );
     items << ( new QStandardItem );
     items << ( new QStandardItem );
     items << ( new QStandardItem );
     items << ( new QStandardItem );
     items << ( new QStandardItem );

     updateRow( document, items );

     if( !parentItem )
     {
          BOOST_FOREACH( const TimePeriod& period, TimePeriod::all() )
          {
               if( period.contains( QDateTime::fromTime_t( document->creationDate() ) ) )
               {
                    QStandardItem* periodItem = itemByPeriod( period );
                    Q_ASSERT( periodItem );

                    periodItem->appendRow( items );

                    break;
               }
          }
     }
     else
     {
          parentItem->appendRow( items );
     }
}
```

Comment: In the example presented, you are not appending items to the model but to QStandardItems which you are obtaining in a way not visible in the example. Can you simplify your code so that it is seen entirely and still reproducible malfunctional?

Comment: @vtmarvin I don't really understand what I have to do, but I put the source file here: http://pastebin.com/RMLqHZhS Hope that help!

Comment: well, if you don't even show the code of MainFilterProxyModel, how are we supposed to see why it doesn't get the signal?

Comment: @nus You are right. Here is proxy header ( http://pastebin.com/pjYsLVs4 ) and source ( http://pastebin.com/udTPS0c6 ) files...

Comment: @mosg I still can't follow the flow of your program because main-model.h is missing. What are model_ and proxy_? Are they data members? Did you try to replace your custom proxy with a standard one just to see if the error is in your proxy or in your main-model?

Answer (score 0):

The base class for modeling is `QAbstractItemModel`. It is better to use the methods of the abstract class to do what you want. `QStandardItemModel` is a simple implementation of the abstract methods of `QAbstractItemModel` and most of the `QStandardItemModel` new methods are used by the reimplemented abstract functions. Here is a code to add item and subitem using the abstract class methods:

```
QAbstractItemModel * pModel = new QStandardItemModel(parent);

int nRows = pModel->rowCount();
pModel->insertRow(nRows); // this will emit rowsAboutToBeInserted() and rowsInserted() signals
pModel->insertColumn(0); // this will emit columnsAboutToBeInserted() and columnsInserted() signals
const QModelIndex indexFirstItem = pModel->index(nRows, 0);
pModel->setData(indexFirstItem, "Item text"); // this will emit dataChanged() signal
int nChildRows = pModel->rowCount(indexFirstItem);
pModel->insertRow(nChildRows, indexFirstItem); // this will emit rowsInserted()
pModel->insertColumn(0, indexFirstItem); // we also need to do this for the item's children
const QModelIndex indexChild = pModel->index(nChildRows, 0, indexFirstItem);
pModel->setData(indexChild, "Child item text");
```

If we try to do the same using QStandardItemModel methods it will look like:

```
QStandardItemModel *pModel = new QStandardItemModel(parent);
QStandardItem *pItem = new QStandardItem("Item text");
pItem->appendRow(new QStandardItem); // pItem is not yet added to pModel and rowsInserted won't be emitted
pModel->appendRow(pItem); // this will probably emit rowsInserted() signal but since we set tha text of the item when creating the pItem the dataChanged() signal won't be emitted.
```

So if you do `pItem->appendRow()` to add sub items and if the pItem is not yet added to the model, you will probably not get the `rowsInserted()` signal and therefore the proxy model won't be notified. From my experience the first method works better and is more robust though you need to write a couple of extra lines. Working directly with `QStandardItemModel` methods will often end with missing signals or other headaches. All you need to look is the `QAbstractItemModel` and `QModelIndex` documentations.